# Install non gem-package as ruby-gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, npm, bower

I have a simple front-end-library that is used for ajax-requests. It can be installed like this:

```
jam install qwest
bower install qwest
npm install qwest --save-dev
```

It's also hosted on github, https://github.com/pyrsmk/qwest.

I wish to use it in a ruby on rails project. Can I somehow include it in my Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

**qwest** can be usually found at rails assets https://rails-assets.org/, but at this moment there seems to be some kind of a problem with the build process.

```
gem 'rails-assets-qwest'
Include following in application.js:
//= require qwest
```

Comment: should I expect this to work even if I can't find the asset on rails-assets?

Comment: No, all the available gems are listed.